# Alternative for Kafka over HTTP Protocol

Tags: java, http, apache-kafka, network-protocols, messagebroker

As you may know Kafka uses a binary protocol in application layer to transfer messages through network, this unknown protocol is problematic in highly secured networks. Are there any message broker tool to be alternative of Kafka over HTTP protocol?

Our Task is to send data from several origins to a single destination over a MAN network.

Open Source and Java based solutions are preferred.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can have a simple HTTP endpoint accepting messages and sending them to kafka.

Comment: Kafka doesn't use any unknown protocol , it is uses TCP

Comment: Is your origin another Kafka Cluster or are you just trying to publish from a remote client over the network? I ask because their are different options for each use case. Also is the data flow one way or bidirectional?

Comment: @khachik I want the communication between producer and broker be over http(s).

Comment: @LijuJohn As in kafka docs this is a binary protocol, but from networks point of view it is not known. Kafka uses TCP in layer 4, out network staff question is about the protocol of application layer protocol.

Comment: @HansJespersen My producers are remote clients and send data over network to broker and data flow is one way.

Comment: Then you should definitely use the Confluent REST Proxy as it runs entirely over HTTP or HTTPS over the WAN. The clients are just regular HTTP clients and they publish with HTTP POST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Kafka-rest](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html) is an http rest proxy for kafka, and support https.

Kafka is using tcp, so it's not really an unknown protocol. You can set ssl or sasl over kafka (https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/security.html and https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, is it free for enterprise applications?!

Comment: Free and open source yes ;)
See here for more info about Confluent products: https://www.confluent.io/product/compare/
On my side I only used open source component so far

Comment: Thanks again dear @treziac for your answer, can I use another tools such as ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ or HornetQ that trasfer messages over http protocol?

Comment: If you want, it depends of your needs and use case, stackoverflow is not the best place for this question. Kafka vs RabbitMQ vs ActiveMQ on google will give you many references

Comment: Fine-grained security can be a problem with kafka-rest or Strimzi bridge.
Other approach can be using Spring Boot (or alternative) + Spring Security (or alternative) + custom REST endpoints like PUSH /my-event, GET /my-event/watch, PUSH /my-event/commit

Answer (score 1):

For people interested in 100% open source option for bridging Apache Kafka to HTTP protocol you can also take a look at [Strimzi Kafka Bridge](https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/). Is also Java based and runs on Kubernetes too.